Does Visual studio code do something with caching python packages in conda environments?
I am super confused about how visual studio works with conda environment. I made a conda environment using the visual studio terminal. Everything okay and works. I want to debug but the file I want to debug is in a folder in the project.
So it is basically folder1 -> folder2 -> main.py
This is giving issues for me as a noob to using debug console. So I decided to switch by opening folder in visual studio code to folder2.
So now it is just folder2 -> main.py
Suddenly all my packages where different. It suddenly didnt have either transformers or nni installed.
Is there something going on with caching that is saved in the one project. If I switch back to the folder1 it is good again. Shouldnt the environment be a bunch of files in the folder that always act the same?
I use windows. Python 10.15.

Did you closed folder 1 and then opened folder2 in vscode?Which means the conda environment is deactivated and you have to reactivate the configured one in terminal.

@AmadeuszLiu Yes, I always activate the environment first. I had two windows open side by side. The command line said the exact same thing. Same path for the environment I was in which I called venv2. Then I did pip freeze in both windows. They both said different things.

If you are trying to use the same venv for 2 folders, I'll suggest creating the venv on these 2 folder's common parent folder so you can use the same venv for both folder.Or change the settings to change default interpreter and venv path.Referriing doc here:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference
